# HTML - Sobrepor uma ul a uma img

Tags: html, css, img

Existe alguma maneira de sobrepor uma ul de links a uma imagem? 
A header da página em que estou trabalhando é feita por imagem mas os links devem ser feitos pelo html.. tem como sobrepor? 
É uma header simples, com um menu que redireciona a outras páginas alinhado a direita e o logo alinhado a esquerda.. nada muito incomum, só não sei como sobrepor os links a imagem. 
 Alguma ideia?

EDIT: É como se meu header tivesse uma propriedade de background-color, mas essa background-color é uma imagem inteira, do tamanho da header (e será a header). Os links serão colocados dentro da header também, mas devem aparecer sobre a imagem, fazendo parte da header.

Comment: Considere fazer um [tour] e adequar sua questão como dito na [help]

Comment: É possível, é simples. Mas ficou meio confuso quando disse "sobrepor os links a imagem". Você quer que as imagens sejam links? Você quer remover os links e inserir imagens no lugar? Explique melhor qual sua dúvida ou poste parte do código para implementarmos.

Comment: A pergunta realmente ficou um pouco confusa, mas como regra geral para sobreposição de elementos no DOM, utilize a propriedade z-index do CSS. A regra dessa propriedade é: elementos com um valor de z-index mais alto se sobrepõe a elementos de valor mais baixo: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Se a imagem deve ficar atrás somente do elemento `ul` você também pode simplesmente colocar como `background-image`. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Editei a pergunta, tentei explicar melhor.. infelizmente não posso postar a imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que eu fiz abaixo foi criam uma `div` para o header, colocar uma imagem em `relative` para poder posicionar a `ul` em `absolute` e posicionar centralizado. Segue o exemplo:

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-seriff;
  color: gold;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#list {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1rem;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://www.debteraser.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/DE_banner-header.jpg" />
  <div id="list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Exemplo 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Exemplo 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Acho que sua dúvida na verdade se resume ao css [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

```
background: url("imagem-exibida-background.jpg") no-repeat 100%;
```

Comment: O único problema que vejo nesta solução, é que dependendo da imagem que ela está usando (que não o culpo já que ela não nos mostrou qual é), ela será dificilmente responsiva.

Comment: Exato, também tenho a responsividade para me preocupar